# @expo/vector-icons not showing on the app hosted as web project in firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, metro-bundler, expo-web

I have an React Native code which I wanted to host on Firebase as a Web app. I've achieved this using the Expo for web. When I deployed the code to Firebase getting console and network error and the icons are not showing. But able to view the icons when the app runs locally.

Tried the suggestions provided in https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/21568 still facing the same.
[image: error]
[image: icon missing]
[local hosted site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snrQx.png)